# Snap image to path in Photoshop CC

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm sure this can be done but not sure how to accomplish it.

I have a rectangle banner layer that I skew for perspective. I have several variations of the rectangle banner that are not skewed, but need to be skewed to exact the same size and position as the first. Note that all have the same original dimensions.

My thought is that I can create a path from the skewed shape, then snap the other banner images to that path so that they skew automatically in the same position. Any suggestions appreciated as I have around 30 to do. I can skew them manually, but it would be much slower and not precise.

Comment: Are they all on one document in different layers or what?

Comment: Instead of skewing each rectangle, why not delete all but the first one that IS skewed and just duplicate the layer 29 more times? Then you have 30 perfectly identical skewed rectangles.

You also mention "banner images". Is your scenario something like you want to have photos in the shape of the original skewed rectangle? If so, just use a mask on a folder and place all the images inside.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I really don't know if it can be done like you say, but I would do the following:

1. Open the original skewed image
2. Open one of the images you need to skew
3. Copy this image and paste it over the original one. Set transparency to 50-60%, enough to see what you're doing with the overlay image while keeping the original image as reference
4. Create an action
5. Now skew the overlay image manually until you're completely satisfied
6. Stop recording action

One you do this, you will simply apply the action to all 30 images. You can do it opening them one by one (is what I'd do for control), or add more steps to the action above

7. After step 6 above, add "save for web" (or export or whatever you want). It's a good idea to save these images somewhere other than your original images folder (*eg: do not overwrite originals!*)
8. after saving, add "close" step

Now you can use `File --> Automate --> Batch` , select the action you just have created and do all 30 images at once.